# Redux state update patterns

Tags: javascript, redux

My question involves redux state updating patterns.

If the state of the redux application looks like the following:

```
{a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3 }
```

---

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({ a: reducerA,
  b: reducerB,
  c: reducerC })
```

and a reducer function modifies the value of `a` how might I then modify the value of `c` when `a` is a certain value?

---

```
function reducerA(
    state = {},
    {type, payload}
) {
   switch(type) {
      case VALUE_CHANGED:
           if(payload.value === someValue){
               /* Change value of state.c here */ 
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: Whenever a value is updated, an event is dispatched. This event is listened by any concerned reducer and will process accordingly. Also, since these update events are queued, multiple events will modify state one after other notifying others about the change

Comment: Reducers usually represent actions: not data transformers.  You may have an action that may change both `c` and `a`.

Comment: If you have combined reducers, you should have one state tree that you can work from, making it easy for different parts of your app to stay in sync.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - So the reducers are combined in a combineReducers function. `let rootReducer = { a: reducerA,
  b: reducerB,
  c: reducerC }; export default combineReducers(rootReducer)`;

Answer (score 0):

**It is inadvisable to update one slice of your Redux Store based on the values of other slices.**

In this example a slice would to one of the values a, b, and c.

`const initialStoreState = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`

a, b and c represent independent parts of your app's state.

Values `a` and  `b` should represent independent slices of app state.

This mean's you shouldn't spread interlinked state across the different values in this object that represents your app state (Redux Store).

Data Normalisation reduces the coupling of state across the slices of the store.

You should strive to normalize the data in your Redux store by avoiding the nesting of data structures.

Have a look at the [Redux Docs Guide to State Normalization](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

> **The basic concepts of normalizing data are**:
>
> Each type of data gets its own "table" in the state.
>
> Each "data table" should store the individual items in an object, with
> the IDs of the items as keys and the items themselves as the values.
>
> Any references to individual items should be done by storing the
> item's ID.
>
> Arrays of IDs should be used to indicate ordering.